# Samsung Note II won't issue OUTGOING_CALL Broadcast

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an app I'm working on where I have a broadcast receiver for outgoing calls. It works fine on the emulator, but not my Galaxy Note 2. It appears that either the Outgoing Call broadcast is never issued, or it's being consumed before I can get a hold of it.

I've heard rumours that Samsung does this funny. Hope someone knows specifically what.

Android Manifest follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <receiver android:name="OutgoingCallHandler" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Apparently it works if I run the settings activity. The Broadcast Receiver doesn't get registered until I do that... Any reason for that?